# PDF preview shows different page after compiling with \include

Tags: compiling, texmaker

I am writing a large document in TexMaker and I am using `\include` and `\includeonly` to save some compilation time, dividing the document in several Tex files. The issue is that now when compiling, the PDF preview jumps to a random page of the document, instead of the newly edited piece, as it was the case then everything was in the same tex. Is there a way to fix that?

Another related feature that it's not working anymore is CTLR+Space which showed in the PDF the part of text editing.